# XCode/Swift: How to get Value of Popup Button

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have a problem. I want to parse a Font Size from a Popup Buttton to a NSFont Function. "fontpt" should replace "15". Whats the right way to do it?

```
let fontpt = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Font Size")
logger.font = NSFont(name: "Menlo Regular", size: 15)
```

Comment: I'd start by storing/reading the font size value as an integer (or float) but not a string.

Comment: Use the itemTitle property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nick says in his comment, save your font size to UserDefaults as a float:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(15.0, forKey: "Font Size")
```

Then when you want to read it:

```
let fontpt = CGFloat(UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "Font Size"))
logger.font = NSFont(name: "Menlo Regular", size: fontpt)
```

Otherwise you'd have to convert your string to a float, and deal with the fact that the Float initializer that takes a string returns an optional:

```
let fontpt = CGFloat(Float(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Font Size")) ?? 14.0)
```

Comment: He or she is talking about getting a text string from the selected item of an NSPopupButton control.

Comment: Exactly. The Values are written to the .plist here:

    @IBAction func font(_ sender: Any) {
        let font = (sender as AnyObject).selectedCell()!.title
        UserDefaults.standard.set(font, forKey: "Font Size")
    }

Comment: Don't post multiple lines of code in a comment. It becomes unreadable due to lack of formatting. Instead edit your question to show the additional code. That makes it easier for other readers anyway.

Comment: I would still recommend converting the input from the `NSPopupButton` to Floats and saving Float values into `UserDefaults`.